# Why does the Google CDN serve un-gzipped jQuery to Chrome users?

Tags: jquery, gzip, cdn, google-cdn

If you check the response headers for `/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js` in Chrome, you will discover that you have been provided with an uncompressed file.

If, however, you do the same in Firefox, you are given the gzipped version.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?